# Cannot start npm sever it fails looking for a directory that has nothing to do with my project

Tags: reactjs, npm

I have a very, very simple React application.  When I run npm start I receive this error.

```
Compiling...
C:\Users\DawsonSchaffer\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js:19
  throw err;
Compiling...
C:\Users\DawsonSchaffer\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js:19
  throw err;
Compiling...
C:\Users\DawsonSchaffer\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js:19
  throw err;
Compiling...
C:\Users\DawsonSchaffer\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js:19
  throw err;
  ^

[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\DawsonSchaffer\Documents\My Music'] {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'stat',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\DawsonSchaffer\\Documents\\My Music'
}

Compiling...
C:\Users\DawsonSchaffer\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js:19
  throw err;
Compiling...
C:\Users\DawsonSchaffer\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js:19
  throw err;
Compiling...
C:\Users\DawsonSchaffer\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js:19
  throw err;
Compiling...
C:\Users\DawsonSchaffer\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js:19
  throw err;
  ^

[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\DawsonSchaffer\Documents\My Music'] {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'stat',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\DawsonSchaffer\\Documents\\My Music'
}
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
    "name": "create-react-app-example",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "react": "^16.10.2",
        "react-dom": "^16.10.2",
        "react-scripts": "3.2.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "react-cosmos": "^5.0.0-beta.15"
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why it's showing My Music directory but that's probably unrelated.  I have installed, reinstall (globally):  webpack, webpack-dev, and react-scripts.  I have cleared the cache severl time to no avail.  I happy to provide more detail, but as of now I'm not sure what else to look for or add.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Dawson

Comment: Put your project in its own folder, not in your home directory of `C:\Users\DawsonSchaffer`

Comment: It's not in my home directory it is in: C:\Users\DawsonSchaffer\Documents\ProjectsDirectory\Projects\first-react-app

Comment: Maybe you ran npm install in `C:\Users\DawsonSchaffer` instead of of your project folder then? You have a `C:\Users\DawsonSchaffer\node_modules` folder which you should probably remove

Answer (score 0):

Andy Ray's comment is probably your best answer. Your project should be in a folder, with everything inside of that.

Answer (score 0):

You were correct I had install it my home folder.  I removed it and reinstalled and it worked.  Thanks for all the help.

Thanks
Dawson